# How to Move an Object on Y-Axis While Its moving X-Axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
   private void Awake()
    {
        _transform = transform;
    }

   

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Time.timeScale <= 0)
            return;

        Vector2 moveWay = Vector2.zero;

        if (Time.time - StartGame.gameStartTime < 3)
        {
            moveWay.y = 1;

            if (speed < maxSpeedOfMovingUp)
            {
                speed += movingUpAcceleration * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            moveWay.y = -1;
            speed = movingDownSpeed;

            if (Vector3.Distance(_transform.position, userCar.position) < 3 && movingCar)
            {
                moveWay.x = transform.position.x;
                Debug.Log("Positioned");
                if (transform.position.x == 0)  
                {
                    moveWay.x = -1;
                    Debug.Log("Left moved");

                }
                else if (transform.position.x == 2) 
                {
                    moveWay.x = 1;
                    Debug.Log("Right moved"); 
                }
              
            }
            else if (Vector3.Distance(_transform.position, userCar.position) <= 10)
            {
                if (point == false)
                {
                    ScoreInfo.İnstance.AddScore(50);
                    point = true;
                }
            }
        }


        _transform.position = _transform.position + new Vector3(moveWay.x, moveWay.y, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

}

So here is my code. The Project is 2D. I want to move movingCar on Y-Axis when it is nearby to userCar. Both cars are moving upwards on the road. When movingCar is near to userCar, it needs to move towards to userCar. I am actually working on this issue for a 3 weeks already. But it seems doesnt work properly. So I wanted different opinion from you guys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this all correct?: This code is for a car that is not the user car. This script decides how much horizontal and vertical movement to apply to this car based on how far it is from the user car (as the crow flies), and whether it has been at least 3 seconds since the game started.

Comment: you didn't explain the behaviour you are experiencing but at a first glance it seems you are always adding two positions (moveWay which is initialised to transform.position.x, but changed if conditions are met) and original position. While this looks like it could work, I have a feeling there will be cases where your position will drift off. I would probably start by initialising moveWay to zero, and working from there

Comment: One problem I see that's going to make your behavior weird is that `speed` is just a number that is completely ignoring horizontal and vertical components of movement. You need to make `speed` into a vector to handle the different components separately.

Comment: I am experiencing the Logs doesnt write on console, like ı want to write log as if car moved to left Log should write "Left Moved" but it doesnt, neither for Right side. And I understood from that that part of code doesnt work at all. @zambari

Comment: If the code is not even executing, you might want to consider re-writing it completely, organising it in a manner more easy to follow. that often helps